# Project in Java, Spring/Show students problem/Wrong implementation with database, SQL

Tags: java, spring, database

I got problem with own project. And exactly it is about showing all students to table. If we get logged (zaloguj sie -> user/test) we don't have any information from database, even button with available classes ;c Can somebody look at it and give me some tips what i can change to take the result ?

https://github.com/Kesshi00/JourneyElectronic

If i do something wrong with my question/unsolved problem, please, forgive me ;)

Greetings,
Tomek!

So, my code (that table i want to show records from sql) in html which doesn't work ->

```
 <tbody>
        <tr th:each="student : ${allStudents}">
            <td th:text="${student.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${student.surname}"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="yes_no" checked>Yes
                <input type="radio" name="yes_no">No
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="yes_no" checked>Yes
                <input type="radio" name="yes_no">No
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="" id="" placeholder="Komentarz"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: please include the relevant code rather than a github link

Comment: There is model attribute allStudents of List type in your loggedcontroller then how can you expect a list to populate? Add that list to your controller should work fine after that.